# How to Work on new development without affecting same production code

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have a development team, with a few development and support projects being supported on the same code line. Recently we started additional changes in existing production module, We use to copy the code into development environment and modify with reference to new chagne request.  We cannot move the development code immediately into production due to project shcedule.
Meanwhile, we are expecting the small small issues to be fixed in production module which need to be fixed in dev environment before fixing in prod, without affecting the new development.

I am aware of using the SCHEMAS in SQL Server 2008, but If I use schema then I need to keep two procedures used for same purpose like file loading, etc. 
I would like to avoid duplication of objects like maintainig in two different schemas.

It totally feels like we're doing it wrong by creating different database or different schemas for same purpose.

Is there a method or tool that anyone's encountered that deals with working on same production code and new development using the production code for simiilar purpose.

Thanks
RTV

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I am in a similar situation. What we've done is simply create two almost identical databases; production and development. The production database feeds our reporting software while the development database is where we are free to test out changes before copying the changes into production. All data loaded into the production database is loaded into the development database through a series of jobs and stored procedures that execute daily. This method, however, does involve extensive duplication of tables, stored procedures, etc., but it is the simplest way we know how to get the functionality we need.